# how to fix Dynamic Multiple Drop Down Menu problem in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu

i have a menu generated dynamically by taking title from database. i have set same table for sub pages by adding a column p_id. and my code looks like this.

```
private $Section = array();
function _menu($root){

    $this->db->select('id,title,p_id');

    $this->db->Where('p_id',$root);

    $this->db->Where('status','active');

    $this->db->Where('type','page');

    $this->db->order_by('sort');

    $query = $this->db->get('pages');

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)

    {

        $this->Section[] = '<ul>';

            $this->Section[] = '<li>';

            $this->Section[] = anchor('site/page/'.$row->id.'#cont_main',$row->title);

            $this->_menu($row->id);

            $this->Section[] = '</li>';

        $this->Section[] = '</ul>';

    }



    $query->free_result();

    return $this->Section;

}



//get menu tree    

function MenuTree(){

    return $this->_menu(0);

}
```

in above _menu() if a nav have two or more child then it doesn't displays because the source populated by it gives extra `</ul> and <ul>`. the source looks like this

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>menu 1 sub1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a>menu 1 sub2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

while i am assuming to get:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>menu 1 sub1</a></li>
        <li><a>menu 1 sub2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**edited**
i have to add menu according to child element. image comes in all menus which doesn't have child too due to extra `<ul></ul>` if i use ul before loop. the source looks like this.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">menu 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a>menu 1 sub1</a>
            <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>menu 1 sub2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

any idea would be appreciable.

Comment: why are you using an MVC framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your `ul` outside the foreach loop AND make sure that you already have results!

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { // we actually have results, open a UL and loop to add the LIs
    $this->Section[] = '<ul>';
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
   $this->Section[] = '<ul>';
```

which of course always displays an `ul` since it does it FOR EACH element. You need to place

```
$this->Section[] = '<ul>';
```

and it's closing block outside the loop. If you want it only triggered if there are more than one parent, an IF statement that check's this and reacts accordingly should by everything you need.

---

The problem that remains seems to be the placing of the `ul`. You could do

```
function MenuTree() {
    return "<ul>" . $this->_menu(0) . "</ul>";
}
```

and remove the mentioned ul from above completely to just get the inner loops.

Comment: @kamal please see my edit. Let my know if this works. You basicly just need to move the outermost `ul` somewhere where it won't be repeated by the recursion.

Comment: @DrColosses: it didn't worked. instead it returns no query->result();